# Native extension from freshplanet crashing on android

Tags: android, facebook, actionscript-3, air, air-native-extension

Hello I am not sure if anyone is familar with Freshplanet's ANE for Facebook(https://github.com/freshplanet). I am using android and my app crashes right after facebook asks me to accept the Facebook permissions. It loads for awhile, then I get a message from andorid, Sorry "appname" has stopped.No other errors are presented just this message. I am quite sure I have set up everything right in terms of including the ANE, but am more sure it has something to do with my code.

This is my code using the ANE inside of flash professional cs6.

```
package {
import com.freshplanet.ane.AirFacebook.Facebook;
import flash.display.MovieClip;

public class Main extends MovieClip {

public function Main() {
var f:Facebook = Facebook.getInstance();
f.init("MYAPPIDGOESHERE");
f.openSessionWithPermissions(["email"]);

    }

}
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Happened to me too.
My problem was not in code but in the Facebook app configuration.
Please make sure your **Package name, Class name and most important Key hash** are correct. This may very well be your problem.

Comment: Update: Freshplanet updated thier ANE and fixed some serious bugs. I advise updating the ANE with the new one.

Answer (score 0):

Did you follow the instructions? You need to add the following to your app.xml file.

```
<android>
    <manifestAdditions><![CDATA[
        <manifest android:installLocation="auto">

            ...

            <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>

            ...

            <application>

                ...

                <activity android:name="com.freshplanet.ane.AirFacebook.LoginActivity" android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen"></activity>
                <activity android:name="com.freshplanet.ane.AirFacebook.DialogActivity" android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen"></activity>
                <activity android:name="com.freshplanet.ane.AirFacebook.ExtendAccessTokenActivity"></activity>

            </application>

        </manifest>
    ]]></manifestAdditions>
</android>
```

https://github.com/freshplanet/ANE-Facebook/blob/master/README.md

Comment: yes I did that otherwise nothing would show up but I get the Facebook permission prompt. My problem is the app is essentially crashing for some reason.